# HPF purpose on motor circuit

Tags: capacitor

[image]

As per circuit above, what's the purpose of the HPF in that array?
The Foot SW is actually an old graphite pile rheostat (which works fine).

Something happened, it got defective I suppose, the circuit went on being continuously closed, thus I removed it along with R1 and the setups works fine without it.

And now I can't figure out its purpose.

I though that HPF's were supposed to block current with low frequencies, based on a calculator it stands at 1Hz for the values given. Well, mine lets even DC current pass, which, I suppose, means it's defective. But if it lets high frequency current pass wouldn't it keep the circuit continuously closed even working?

Comment: Run capacitor in series with the only winding? Something stinks here. Without that, I'd assume it's something like a sewing machine (brushed) motor. And I have seen one run away when the 100nF capacitor failed short circuit. Replaced with a modern Class X2 cap, working fine.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, it's an YDF motor, pedal and all that came with a Privileg sewing machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphite rheostat may get a little "noisy" with age due to poor contact at worn positions. Any making and breaking of the contact would have two effects:

- Arcing with further burning of the affected zone. This would be exacerbated by the inductive characteristics of the motor.
- High-frequency emissions from the wiring. I would guess that this might be less of a concern but perhaps it dates from the days of medium and long wave radios which would have been more susceptible to low-frequency EMI (as they operate in the high kilo-hertz region).

As you state, the capacitor would act as a high-pass filter (HPF) shorting out the high-frequency components of the noise. The resistor is probably there to discharge the capacitor so that anyone unplugging the device from the mains wouldn't get a tingle from the plug pins if touched. (I had a computer that must have had a small capacitor across the 230 V input. It's quite a surprise to get a jolt from the mains plug pins.)

> I though that HPF's were supposed to block current with low frequencies ...

Correct, and the opposite view that HPFs pass high frequencies.

> ... based on a calculator it stands at 1Hz for the values given.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbtRYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A high-pass filter. (b) A different high-pass filter.*

You may be confusing the standard high-pass RC filter with the purpose of this circuit. The resistor you should be considering is that of the motor which will be, perhaps, in the order of 100 Ω or so. The corner frequency would then be \$ \frac {1}{2 \pi RC} = \frac {1}{2 \pi 100 \cdot 100n} = 16~kHz \$.

> But if it lets high frequency current pass wouldn't it keep the circuit continuously closed even working?

You don't need to worry about that. The impedance of a 100 nF capacitor is given by \$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi fC} \$. At 50 Hz this works out to be \$ \frac {1}{2 \pi 50 \cdot 100n} \approx 32~k \Omega \$ so a tiny current will pass through it.